# css stacking div

Tags: css

I am tying to stack divs to show a top and bottom fade using and image.

The outer div ("rotator") has a background image that has a gradient at the top and bottom and transparent in the middle.  In the middle I want to show content or an image and have the outer div background image on top so you always will see the gradients on top and bottom and the content/image behind.

Thanks for any help.  Right now the background image always gets covered by the inner div content/image.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="rotator">
<div class="content">this is my content</div>
</div>

#rotator 
{
    width:990px;
    height:300px;
    background: url('../Images/TIBC_Base/featured_area.png') repeat-x;
z-index:99;

}
#rotator .content
{
    width:990px;
    height:300px;
z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: With background image: http://jsfiddle.net/TgQ5s/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added new `.image-frame` div inside the `#rotator` with following styles for bring shadow on `.content`. and check the updated [code](http://jsfiddle.net/TgQ5s/5/).

```
#rotator 
{
    width:990px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
}
.image-frame{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: url('http://i47.tinypic.com/2lctevc.png') repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you using z-index property the **position** property must needed , try using something like

**postition : relative**

```
<div id="rotator">
<div class="content">this is my content</div>
</div>

    #rotator 
    {
        width:990px;
        height:300px;
        background: url('../Images/TIBC_Base/featured_area.png') repeat-x;
    position:relative;
    z-index:99;


    }

    #rotator .content
    {
        width:990px;
        height:300px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
    }
```

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle with the background image attached. http://jsfiddle.net/TgQ5s/1/

Comment: Thanks senthilbp, but that did not seem to do the trick.  The content is still overtop the background.